# Can't add criteria to geom_text when using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-wrap, geom-text

I'm trying to create a figure in r using ggplot2, I use facet_wrap to duplicate 3 sets of stacked bar graphs for different type of setting. However when I use geom_text to only label values that are more than 1.5, I received this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 24 rows, data has 16
```

Please advise

Here's my code for the graph:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = percent, fill = facility,label = round(percent))) + geom_bar(aes(y = percent, x = year, fill = facility), 
           data = data,stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(x=year, y =percent),linetype="dashed",color="black", position = 'stack',data = data)+
  geom_text(data = subset(data,percent>1.5),size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),color="white")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(suffix = "%", prefix = "")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:1,
                     labels=c("2010","2015"))+
  labs(x="", y="Percentage") +
  ggtitle("Year comparison") +
  coord_flip()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20,face="bold",hjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~data$type, ncol = 1, scales = "free")
```

[Here is the image... I'm basically trying to get rid of the label 0 in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tvkp.png)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing your `facet_wrap()`, you're including the full column of "type" (`data$type`) from the original dataframe, presumably 24 rows long. You want to use a form like `facet_wrap(~ type)` to allow `ggplot2` to use the data dynamic to the facet.

A little hard to explain, but maybe easy to play around with in sample data.

**Won't work**

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, label = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = subset(iris, Sepal.Length > 6)) +
  facet_wrap(~ iris$Species)
#> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = structure(c(1L, 1L, : replacement has 150 rows, data has 61
```

**Will work**

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, label = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = subset(iris, Sepal.Length > 6)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```